# "no changes found" when issuing hg push, but there are changes

Tags: mercurial, kiln

Trying to push to a Kiln repo.  There are definitely changes, lots of them, `hg status` lists 238 files changed.  There is a  warning that the certificate with fingerprint blah blah is not verified -- though if it's just a warning why would it interfere with the push?

Full output:

```
pushing to https://mydomain/Code/Repositories/Group/myrepo
warning: mydomain certificate with fingerprint fe:ab:65:89:7c:6f:1a:21:a8:39:54:6c:2a:cb:ca:ae:e9:e5:f0:01 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
warning: developers.kilnhg.com certificate with fingerprint fe:ab:65:89:7c:6f:1a:21:a8:39:54:6c:2a:cb:ca:ae:e9:e5:f0:01 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
searching for changes
searching for changes
no changes found
```

Googling this has turned up nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to commit your changes to the local repository before you can push the resulting changeset to a remote repository. Use the command `hg commit` to do so.

Comment: ugh sorry, I should have known that.